# Difficulty linking hyperlink to macro in excel mac

Tags: vba

I have looked up this problem so many times and it still doesnt seem to work for me. I am learning VBA and as a practice project am trying to make a nutritional tracker. I am trying to make a hyperlink that, when clicked, runs a macro to add a new food entry row. Here is my NewFoodEntry():

```
Sub NewFoodEntry()
'
' NewFoodEntry Macro
' Insert new food entry row.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Option+Cmd+Shift+N
'
' Setting selection as input cell'
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Selection

' Select default food entry row'

    Range(myRange.Offset(-1, 0), myRange.Offset(-1, 7)).Select
    Selection.Copy

'Insert default food entry row below myRange selection'
    myRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    myRange.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Select correct Totals cell'
    Dim totalsRange As Range
    Set totalsRange = Sheets("Nutrition").Range("D:D").Find("Totals", After:=myRange.Offset(0, 3), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    Debug.Print totalsRange.Address

'Select correct Calories cell'

    Dim caloriesRange As Range
    Set caloriesRange = Sheets("Nutrition").Range("E:E").Find("Calories", After:=totalsRange.Offset(0, 1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If caloriesRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Calories still not found."

    Else
        Debug.Print caloriesRange.Address

    End If

'Select correct Protein cell'

    Dim proteinRange As Range
    Set proteinRange = Sheets("Nutrition").Range("F:F").Find("Protein", After:=totalsRange.Offset(0, 2), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If proteinRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Protein still not found."

    Else
        Debug.Print proteinRange.Address

    End If

'Select correct Carbs cell'

    Dim carbsRange As Range
    Set carbsRange = Sheets("Nutrition").Range("G:G").Find("Carbs", After:=totalsRange.Offset(0, 3), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If carbsRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Carbs still not found."

    Else
        Debug.Print carbsRange.Address

    End If

'Select correct Fat cell'

    Dim fatRange As Range
    Set fatRange = Sheets("Nutrition").Range("H:H").Find("Fat", After:=totalsRange.Offset(0, 4), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If fatRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Fat still not found."

    Else
        Debug.Print fatRange.Address

    End If

    'Calculate Calories Total

    totalsRange.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & caloriesRange.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & totalsRange.Offset(-1, 1).Address & ")"

    'Calculate Protein Total

    totalsRange.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=SUM(" & proteinRange.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & totalsRange.Offset(-1, 2).Address & ")"

    'Calculate Carbs Total

    totalsRange.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=SUM(" & carbsRange.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & totalsRange.Offset(-1, 3).Address & ")"

    'Calculate Fat Total

    totalsRange.Offset(0, 4).Formula = "=SUM(" & fatRange.Offset(1, 0).Address & ":" & totalsRange.Offset(-1, 4).Address & ")"


End Sub
```

That is under the "module 1" of my VBA editor.

Now I also went to the proper sheet object ("nutrition") in my VBA editor and entered the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$37" Then 
        Debug.Print "It worked"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

I can't seem to get this code to work. Clicking the hyperlink doesn't print to the immediate window. Obviously, running the macro via the hyperlink doesnt work either. Here is a screenshot of my excel so you get an idea of what im trying to do.

[Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E65V4.png)

I should also add that this is the code I used to convert a cell text to a hyperlink:

```
Sub HyperActive()

'Make a hyperlink

    Dim nm As String

    nm = ActiveSheet.Name & "!"
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Text
        addy = nm & r.Address(0, 0)
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            addy, TextToDisplay:=r.Text
    Next r
End Sub
```

EDIT:
After much frustration, I have found that the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink does not work on Macs after Excel 2010. I do not know why or if this is actually true, so if anyone has anymore insight into this, let me know.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac/mac-excel-2011-hyperlinks-dont-work-as-buttons/41192768-45fd-47db-ad8c-f614fc83be5a

Comment: Also, I'm certain my NewFoodEntry() is probably terribly inefficient and not coded in the cleanest way, but I'm really just looking for advice on getting the hyperlink to work. Still, any advice on cleaning up my macro code will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't replicate this - it works fine when I test your code. Try putting `Debug.Print Target.Range.Address` *outside* of the `If` statement to make sure that A, the event handler is firing, and B, that the value of `Target.Range.Address` is what you expect.

Comment: I tried it and I still am getting nothing printed in the immediate window. I tried reopening the excel file but it still doesnt work. I click the hyperlink and nothing happens. No print. No macro if I change the code to Run(NewFoodEntry).

Comment: That means your event handler isn't firing.  Try dropping `Application.EnableEvents = True` in a test sub and running it.

Comment: Where exactly do you put that comment? I put it in the Worksheet_FollowHyperlink() sub and that didnt work. I also made a separate sub called TestSub() and tried it in there too. Still didn't do anything. Hyperlink still isnt printing to the immediate window.

Comment: You can put it anywhere.  Running it just ensures that events aren't disabled.  If you put a breakpoint on `If Target.Range.Address = "$A$37" Then ` do you hit it when you click on the hyperlink?

Comment: So i put a breakpoint where you instructed in the sheet1 code and clicked the hyperlink. Nothing happens. Not sure if im doing it correctly.

Comment: Is there anyway I can just send you my excel document and you mess around to see if you encounter the same problem? It's like clicking the hyperlink creates absolutely no response.

Comment: @dylan russell You could upload it to mediafire, and state the URL to the file in your question